# Changing image of UIButton via click - Swift

Tags: swift, uibutton, uikit

Im getting an error with this code..
What it should do: When user taps button, the image changes to checked, taps again, changes to Unchecked.

Im getting the error: AnyObject doesnt have member names 'setImage ...

```
 @IBAction func tick(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let image = UIImage(named:"Unchecked") {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"Checked.png"), forControlState: .Normal)
    }
    if let image = UIImage(named:"Checked") {
        sender.setImage( UIImage(named:"Unchecked.png"), forControlState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only needs to change (sender:AnyObject) to (sender:UIButton) 
as below

```
@IBAction func tick(sender: UIButton) {
    if let image = UIImage(named:"Unchecked") {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"Checked.png"), forControlState: .Normal)
    }
    if let image = UIImage(named:"Checked") {
        sender.setImage( UIImage(named:"Unchecked.png"), forControlState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked. I also had to change forControlState to forState..whatever that mean.. anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly tell your `compiler` that `sender` is a `UIButton` and not `AnyObject` type.

```
    @IBAction func tick(sender: AnyObject) {
     if let button = sender as! UIbutton {
        if let image = UIImage(named:"Unchecked") {
            button.setImage(UIImage(named:"Checked.png"), forControlState: .Normal)
        }
        if let image = UIImage(named:"Checked") {
            button.setImage( UIImage(named:"Unchecked.png"), forControlState: .Normal)
        }
      } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
var checked = false

@IBAction func tick(sender: UIButton) {

    if checked {
        sender.setImage( UIImage(named:"Unchecked.png"), forState: .Normal)
        checked = false
    } else {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"Checked.png"), forState: .Normal)
        checked = true
    }
}
```